# Show all post titles

Tags: posts, categories

I want to make a parallax type link, but I have no idea how to go about it yet. I need to get all post titles with # link and then I can try the parallax thing.

My current category page code bellow. I want to show all post in there..

```
<div class="content">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <h2><?php single_cat_title('',true); ?></h2>


   <dl>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

           ?>
    <dt><?php the_title(); ?></dt>
    <dd><?php the_content(); ?></dd>
    <?php endwhile; 
            ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </dl>
  </div>
```

I get all post titles with content nicely. No problem .. but I want to add one div after H2 then want to show

```
<ul>
<li data-slide="1">title </li>
<li data-slide="2">title </li>
<li data-slide="3">title </li>
<li data-slide="4">title </li>
...
..

</ul>
```

How could I do that?

Category page will be like bellow

```
**Category Title**

All Post Title (list)



(under all post )

--------------
Post title
Post Content
---------------

Post title
Post Content
---------------

Post title
Post Content
---------------

Post title
Post Content
---------------

Post title
Post Content
---------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found one way. and is showing properly. .but i am not sure is that perfect way or not. please give your suggestion

```
  <ul>  
    <?php
$test = get_the_title();
$args = array( 'cat_name' => $test );
$args = array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query );
get_posts( $args ); while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>

<li data-slide="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></li>

<?php } ?>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have not tested it but this should get you to your goal.   I believe Accore LTD has it correct as well, except your slide #s will be post ID, instead of slide-1, slide-2

```
<div class="content">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <h2><?php single_cat_title('',true); ?></h2>
 <div>
   <ul>
     <?php 
     $inc = 1;
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <li data-slide="<?php echo $inc; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
     $inc++;
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php else : ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks. actually i want to show title alone then again show one by one title and post. so it mean title will show two time. one time with content and another time on top all just title.just after h2

Comment: If I understand your goal, you want something like this?
    Title 1
    Title 2

    Title 1
    Content 1 content 1 content1

    Title 2
    Content 2 content 2 content2

Comment: no.. not really...let how i want out out

Category title

ALL post title
------------------------
Post Title
Post Content
------------------------
Post Title
Post Content
------------------------
Post Title
Post Content

Comment: Having trouble formatting that in comment.  Can you add an example with the title two times in your question?

Comment: i just update my post .. see how i wanted category page. i already solve it .. bellow i post my code. but now i want to know is there any other nice or easy way to do

thanks @jdm2112